# How to create separate swap partitions for 2 linux distro

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, swap, kali

I have triple booted my laptop with those OS and also installed them in this order: Windows 8.1 Pro, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, Kali 2.0

When installing Ubuntu, I also created a swap area (8 GB) for it to use (Partition 5 - /dev/sda5)

When intalling Kali, I created another swap area (8 GB) for it (Partition 7 - /dev/sda7)

However I now see that Kali has a swap area of about 16 GB, and Ubuntu has none when looking at the system monitor on both OS. How can I make those 2 distributions use their own separate Swap Area?

Answer (score 0):

SWAP is just an "extension" of the RAM. You dont need SWAP partitions for every distro, you can use the same SWAP space for every distro you have installed on you drive, just map it right in your fstab and thats it!!

Comment: That is not the answer for this question. Eclipse22 wants to know how to create swap partition for each OS ;)

Comment: You are right...I just wanted to tell him that it is not necessary to have a SWAP partition for every distro and that he throws away his disk space!! My bad if the post is not appropriate or didnt help :S

Answer (score 0):

Check `/etc/fstab` on each system, and read `man fstab`. For example, on my system (YMMV):

```
$ grep swap /etc/fstab
# swap was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=339b7a56-3b67-47e8-87e1-f483296a39bd none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

Also, to see how swap is set up at boot time you could read the init scripts found by

```
 grep swap /etc/init/* /etc/init.d/*
```

Another source of information is `man -k swap`